# Trouble with edited applescript

Tags: compilation, applescript

I just edited the file `new item alert.scpt` in the /Macintosh HD/Library/Scripts/Folder Actions.../ folder. I managed to save it after editing some permissions, but when I click `Run` or `Compile` nothing happens.

Is this a common error, or do I have a problem in my applescript if someone wouldn't mind taking a look.

```
property Docs : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Docs"
property Music : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Music"
property Videos : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Videos"
property Images : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Images"
property Profiles : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:iPhone:Profiles"
property Zips : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Zips"
property PSDs : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:PSDs"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            --get the name of the folder
            set the folder_name to the name of this_folder
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".png") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".JPEG") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".gif") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".jpg") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".jpeg") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".PNG") then
                move eachitem to folder Images
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".mov") then
                move eachitem to folder Videos
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".avi") then
                move eachitem to folder Videos
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".wma") then
                move eachitem to folder Videos
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".m4v") then
                move eachitem to folder Videos
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".mp4") then
                move eachitem to folder Music
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".mp3") then
                move eachitem to folder Music
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".wav") then
                move eachitem to folder Music
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".wma") then
                move eachitem to folder Music
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".pdf") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".doc") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".docx") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".pages") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".ppt") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".pptx") then
                move eachitem to folder Docs
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".mobileprovision") then
                move eachitem to folder Profiles
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".zip") then
                move eachitem to folder Zips
            end if
            if (name of eachitem ends with ".psd") then
                move eachitem to folder PSDs
            end if


        end tell

        -- find out how many new items have been placed in the folder
        set the item_count to the number of items in the added_items
        --create the alert string
        set alert_message to ("Folder Actions Alert:" & return & return) as Unicode text
        if the item_count is greater than 1 then
            set alert_message to alert_message & (the item_count as text) & " new items have "
        else
            set alert_message to alert_message & "One new item has "
        end if
        set alert_message to alert_message & "been placed in folder " & «data utxt201C» & the folder_name & «data utxt201D» & "."
        set the alert_message to (the alert_message & return & return & "Would you like to view the added items?")

        display dialog the alert_message buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2 with icon 1 giving up after dialog_timeout
        set the user_choice to the button returned of the result

        if user_choice is "Yes" then
            tell application "Finder"
                --go to the desktop 
                activate
                --open the folder
                open this_folder
                --select the items
                reveal the added_items
            end tell
        end if
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder action scripts are not supposed to be run directly. It's associated to any number of folders via the context menu of those folders.

Then, whenever that folder's content change, the script is triggered, and the `on adding folder items to` handler is run.

So, you should just right-click the folder you want to attach the script, and choose `Set folder action` menu item.

Also, you're not supposed to overwrite the system-provided file... you can save your customized version in your own home directory and you can attach it to any folder.

Comment: I just did that and created a new script with the code in, but whenever I add an item to the folder, nothing happens. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I just get an alert asking if I would like to view this file.

Comment: That's exactly what your script, after the line `    --create the alert string` is doing. So, your code is at least launched by the fonder action, but your code is not doing what you intend to do. I guess that should be another question on Stack Overflow, independent of what you have just asked ...

Answer (score 0):

A folder action handler will fail silently, so if there is an error the script will abort.  In your posted script, you are not going through the added items at all, and you are using an undefined variable - **eachitem**.  Also note that using a **try** statement without the **on error** part will just eat any and all errors, which doesn't help with debugging, either.  I know you are using one of Apple's example scripts, but that thing is pretty old.

I've found that the best approach when using folder actions is to put the main part(s) of the script outside of the folder action handler so that it can also be run normally (a script doesn't need to be dedicated to just being a folder action) - this helps with debugging, and can also give you an applet or droplet.  For testing, you can also comment out the folder action handler declaration and add statements to get the folder and files.

I hope you don't mind, but I took the liberty of rearranging your script so that it can also be run from the Script Editor:

```
property Docs : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Docs"
property Music : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Music"
property Videos : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Videos"
property Images : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Images"
property Profiles : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:iPhone:Profiles"
property Zips : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:Zips"
property PSDs : "Macintosh HD:Users:Max:Downloads:PSDs"

property dialogTimeout : 10


on run -- script run as an application or from the Script Editor
    set someFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed) -- manually get some files
    tell application "Finder" to set containingFolder to (container of first item of someFiles) as alias
    doStuff(containingFolder, someFiles)
end run


on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items -- folder action handler
    doStuff(this_folder, added_items)
end adding folder items to


on doStuff(theFolder, theStuff) -- do stuff with file items in a folder
    set numberOfItems to (count theStuff)
    tell application "Finder"
        set folderName to name of theFolder
        repeat with anItem in theStuff
            if name extension of anItem is in {"png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"} then
                move anItem to folder Images
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"mov", "avi", "wma", "m4v"} then
                move anItem to folder Videos
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"mp4", "mp3", "wav", "wma"} then
                move anItem to folder Music
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"pdf", "doc", "docx", "pages", "ppt", "pptx"} then
                move anItem to folder Docs
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"mobileprovision"} then
                move anItem to folder Profiles
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"zip"} then
                move anItem to folder Zips
            else if name extension of anItem is in {"psd"} then
                move anItem to folder PSDs
            else
                -- no match, so leave it
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell

    -- create the alert string
    set alertText to ("Folder Actions Alert:" & return & return) as Unicode text
    if numberOfItems is greater than 1 then
        set alertText to alertText & numberOfItems & " new items have "
        set plural to "s"
    else
        set alertText to alertText & "One new item has "
        set plural to ""
    end if
    set alertText to alertText & "been added to the folder " & «data utxt201C» & folderName & «data utxt201D» & "."
    set alertText to alertText & return & return & "Would you like to view the added item" & plural & "?"

    display dialog alertText buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2 with icon 1 giving up after dialogTimeout

    if (button returned of the result) is "Yes" then tell application "Finder"
        activate
        -- open theFolder
        reveal theStuff
    end tell
end doStuff
```